# Can we select any random class while running Java -Jar command

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

Can we select any random class while running Java -Jar command or only one entry class can be specified while building jar (maven or settings.gradle)

in spark we can call any random class while running spark submit, can we do that in Java??

Comment: Only on entry point can be used but from there you can call any class.

Answer (score 0):

Any class that contains a `public static void main(String[] args)` method (the parameter can also be `String args[]` or `String... args)` all three are the same). **But**, instead of `-jar` you must use `-cp` to control the classpath; the entry-point of a jar file is controlled (and specified) by the `Main-Class` entry in the [MANIFEST](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html).